# ASIHTTPRequest Disabling Cache

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, asihttprequest, asiformdatarequest

I have an application which logs into an online site using POST form being sent from ASIHTTPRequest & ASIFormDataRequest.

I have a log in box, a .xib where user enters their details. Then as they click OK, it connects to the site with the details user has entered. It sends the form OK etc.

But there is a problem. I enter the incorrect details first, it connects and tells me the html of response. I can tell from the html that the details are incorrect. Now i enter the correct details, and ASI* does not even bother connecting.
When I enter the correct details first, it tells me a different html which is supposed to show whenever I enter the right log in details.
So the problem is in cache, because it doesn't bother connecting again on second request, right?

I am using Little Snitch.app, so i know when it connects, and when it does not.

Now, the question sounds: "How do I disable Cache in ASIRequests?"

Thanks a lot.

Snippet of class: http://pastebin.com/a83YCpnm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found out what the trouble was. I did not reallocate the ASIFormDataRequest & ASIHTTPRequest on each request, which was causing the trouble on other requests because it was being reused.

Therefore the request has been marked as complete and so it did not even bother making another request if that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ASIHTTPRequest doesn't cache POST responses by default - see the following code in ASIHTTPRequest.m

```
if (![[self requestMethod] isEqualToString:@"GET"]) {
    [self setDownloadCache:nil];
}
```

There's clearly something else going on - are you sure it's a POST request you're making? How are you enabling caching / creating the request, can you post some code please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/a83YCpnm < here is a snippet of the class. I did not configure any caching yet. I tried to set the cachePolicy to nil, and other attributes it can take but it did not work. i will try setDownloadCache tho.